# Virtual Box configured with 8 cpus but nproc in vm shows 1

Tags: linux, virtualbox, virtual-machine, cpu

I created and configured VM with 8 cpus, (at server with 48 cpus).
Here `vboxmanage showvminfo` output:

```
  Memory size:     40960MB
    Page Fusion:     off
    VRAM size:       8MB
    CPU exec cap:    100%
    HPET:            off
    Chipset:         piix3
    Firmware:        BIOS
    Number of CPUs:  8
    PAE:             on
    Long Mode:       on
    CPUID Portability Level: 0

When i login to vm, and use command `nproc` the output is 1.
```

Also the output of `cat /proc/cpuinfo` is:

```
processor   : 0
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 63
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2680 v3 @ 2.50GHz
stepping    : 2
cpu MHz     : 2495.836
cache size  : 30720 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 1
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 1
apicid      : 0
initial apicid  : 0
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 15
```

`uname -a` output:

```
Linux node1.cluster 3.19.0-25-generic #26~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 24 21:16:20 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

`lscpu` output:

```
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                1
On-line CPU(s) list:   0
Thread(s) per core:    1
Core(s) per socket:    1
Socket(s):             1
NUMA node(s):          1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 63
Stepping:              2
CPU MHz:               2495.836
BogoMIPS:              4991.67
Hypervisor vendor:     KVM
Virtualization type:   full
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              256K
L3 cache:              30720K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0
```

Is that how it suppose to be? Or perhaps i doing something wrong?

Comment: What do `uname -a` and `lscpu` output?

Comment: edited @grawity

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the relevant VirtualBox settings for this VM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem.

I forgot to  enable the I/O APIC for virtual machines that I intend to use in 64-bit mode.

`vboxmanage modifyvm "Node1" --ioapic on` 
sovled the problem. My bad.